# Best practice when altering a parent theme function inside a child theme?

Tags: functions, child-theme

So Im not entirely sure what the best way to accomplish this task is exactly. I tried out some things just to see what worked but I have no idea if how I accomplished this task is the most appropriate way, so Im hoping some much smarter folks than myself can enlighten me hopefully...

In short, the theme that I'm child theming seems to aggregately use functions in order to execute different blocks of code for the themes layout.

The code that I needed to make some small alterations to were contained within multiple functions inside the parent theme, and the only way that I figured out via trial and error to make my changes work inside my child theme was to copy over the functions that needed to be changed from the parent theme, and then simply re-declare them by appending the name of the function slightly.

This worked fine, but I have no idea if this is bad practice so I wanted to double check with the community on what the best way to approach this sorta thing would be.

> All thats really being changed is Im removing the avatar that is being
>   marked up in the header.

The original set of functions from the parent theme:

```
/**
 * This function contains large post title markup.
 * It is used in 'flexia_post_large_title' method.
 *
 * @since  v0.0.5
 */
function flexia_post_large_title_markup() {
    $thumbnail = '';
        if (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) {
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                 $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
            }
        }
    ?>
    <header class="page-header single-blog-header" <?php if ( ! empty( $thumbnail ) ) : ?>
    style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_attr($thumbnail); ?>');" <?php endif; ?> <?php if ( empty( $thumbnail ) ) : ?>
    style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_attr(get_header_image()); ?>');" <?php endif; ?>>
        <div class="header-inner">
            <div class="header-content">
                <?php the_title( '<h1 class="blog-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
                <?php flexia_post_large_title_author_avatar_markup(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-overlay"></div>
    </header>
    <?php
}

/**
 * This function contains large post title author avatar markup.
 * It is used in 'flexia_post_large_title_markup' method.
 *
 * @since  v0.0.5
 */
function flexia_post_large_title_author_avatar_markup() {

    if( class_exists( 'CMB2_Bootstrap_230' ) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_title_header_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_flexia_post_meta_key_header_meta', true );
        $post_title_header_post_author = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_flexia_post_meta_key_header_author_meta', true );
        if( $post_title_header_meta == 'yes' || $post_title_header_meta == NULL ) {
            if( $post_title_header_post_author == 'yes' || $post_title_header_post_author == NULL ) {
            ?>
            <div class="blog-author">
                <div class="author-avatar">
                    <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 'flexia-thumbnail-avatar' ); ?>
                    <div class="author-body">
                        <h4 class="author-heading"><?php the_author(); ?></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }else {
        ?>
        <div class="blog-author">
            <div class="author-avatar">
                <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 'flexia-thumbnail-avatar' ); ?>
                <div class="author-body">
                    <h4 class="author-heading"><?php the_author(); ?></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
/**
 *
 */
function flexia_post_large_title_header_meta_markup() {
    ?>
    <header class="entry-header single-blog-meta single-post-meta-large">
        <?php
        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php flexia_updated_on(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php
        endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <?php
}

/**
 * This function will show/hide large post title
 *
 * @since  v0.0.5
 */
function flexia_post_large_title() {
    $flexia_single_posts_layout = get_theme_mod('flexia_single_posts_layout', 'flexia_single_posts_layout_large');
    if( class_exists( 'CMB2_Bootstrap_230' ) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_flexia_post_meta_key_page_title', true );
        $post_title_header_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_flexia_post_meta_key_header_meta', true );
        if( $post_title == 'default' || $post_title == NULL ) {
            if( $flexia_single_posts_layout == 'flexia_single_posts_layout_large' ) {
                flexia_post_large_title_markup();
                if( $post_title_header_meta == 'yes' || $post_title_header_meta == NULL ) {
                    flexia_post_large_title_header_meta_markup();
                }
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }elseif( $post_title == 'large') {
            flexia_post_large_title_markup();
            if( $post_title_header_meta == 'yes' || $post_title_header_meta == NULL ) {
                flexia_post_large_title_header_meta_markup();
            }
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }else {
        if( $flexia_single_posts_layout == NULL || $flexia_single_posts_layout == 'flexia_single_posts_layout_large' ) {
            flexia_post_large_title_markup();
            flexia_post_large_title_header_meta_markup();
        }
    }

}
```

My crude attempt at amending the code in order to make some simple changes to the markup which is placed in my child theme's `functions.php`:

> (Ive commented out the parts that Ive deleted from the original
>   function so you can see what Ive removed easier)

```
// This function contains large post title markup.
// It is used in 'flexia_post_large_title' method.

function hbps_flexia_post_large_title_markup() {
    $thumbnail = '';
        if (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) {
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                 $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
            }
        }
    ?>
    <header class="page-header single-blog-header" <?php if ( ! empty( $thumbnail ) ) : ?>
    style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_attr($thumbnail); ?>');" <?php endif; ?> <?php if ( empty( $thumbnail ) ) : ?>
    style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_attr(get_header_image()); ?>');" <?php endif; ?>>
        <div class="header-inner">
            <div class="header-content">
                <?php the_title( '<h1 class="blog-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-overlay"></div>
    </header>
    <?php
}

// Change blog header titles by removing Avatar and including By: before Author

// This function contains large post title author avatar markup.
// It is used in 'flexia_post_large_title_markup' method.

function hbps_flexia_post_large_title_author_avatar_markup() {

    if( class_exists( 'CMB2_Bootstrap_230' ) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_title_header_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_flexia_post_meta_key_header_meta', true );
        $post_title_header_post_author = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_flexia_post_meta_key_header_author_meta', true );
        if( $post_title_header_meta == 'yes' || $post_title_header_meta == NULL ) {
            if( $post_title_header_post_author == 'yes' || $post_title_header_post_author == NULL ) {
            ?>
            <div class="blog-author">
                <div class="author-avatar">

                        <!-- DELETE AVATAR IN HEADER -->
<!--                    <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 'flexia-thumbnail-avatar' ); ?> -->

                    <div class="author-body">
                        <h4 class="author-heading">By: <?php the_author(); ?></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }else {
        ?>
        <div class="blog-author">
            <div class="author-avatar">

                    <!-- DELETE AVATAR IN HEADER -->
<!--                <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 'flexia-thumbnail-avatar' ); ?> -->

                <div class="author-body">
                    <h4 class="author-heading">By: <?php the_author(); ?></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}

function hbps_flexia_post_large_title_header_meta_markup() {
    ?>
    <header class="entry-header single-blog-meta single-post-meta-large">
        <?php
        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php flexia_updated_on(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php
        endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <?php
}

// This function will show/hide large post title

function hbps_flexia_post_large_title() {
    $flexia_single_posts_layout = get_theme_mod('flexia_single_posts_layout', 'flexia_single_posts_layout_large');
    if( class_exists( 'CMB2_Bootstrap_230' ) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_flexia_post_meta_key_page_title', true );
        $post_title_header_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_flexia_post_meta_key_header_meta', true );
        if( $post_title == 'default' || $post_title == NULL ) {
            if( $flexia_single_posts_layout == 'flexia_single_posts_layout_large' ) {
                hbps_flexia_post_large_title_markup();
                if( $post_title_header_meta == 'yes' || $post_title_header_meta == NULL ) {
                    hbps_flexia_post_large_title_header_meta_markup();
                }
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }elseif( $post_title == 'large') {
            hbps_flexia_post_large_title_markup();
            if( $post_title_header_meta == 'yes' || $post_title_header_meta == NULL ) {
                hbps_flexia_post_large_title_header_meta_markup();
            }
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }else {
        if( $flexia_single_posts_layout == NULL || $flexia_single_posts_layout == 'flexia_single_posts_layout_large' ) {
            hbps_flexia_post_large_title_markup();
            hbps_flexia_post_large_title_header_meta_markup();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the name of the function along with the needed modifications and copy it to child theme's function file, then in original file you need to search for `add_filter` or `add_action` and in child theme you can unhook original functions using `remove_filter` or `remove_action` and the you can use `add_filter` or `add_action` with your new function.
In short you can simple find the `add_action` or `add_filter` for these modified functions, copy them and just rename from add to remove, then again you can copy the `add_action` or `add_filter` from the original theme and this time you can replace the name of the function.

Update:
For this specific theme, you don't need `add_filter` or `remove_filter` because the function `flexia_post_large_title_author_avatar_markup` is directly called at line 174, and maybe it's not used at any other place so it's not hooked to any action, and same for the second function

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's what Ive done, but I did not add `remove_filter` or `remove_action`... will that cause problems if left out?

Comment: you need to remove the functions which you don't need, so it won't cause any problem :)

Comment: There are no `add_filter` or `add_action` present. Copying over the function(s) to the child theme and renaming the function is what worked for me though. ie. `function flexia_post_large_title_author_avatar_markup() {` >>> `function hbps_flexia_post_large_title_author_avatar_markup() {`

Comment: sounds good, if you this helped the you can accept this answer so if anyone in future faces same issue they can solve by this answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer stating why it worked for you just by renaming

Comment: Thank you, that is why I wanted to ask... because it seemed suspicious that it should work doing it this way. Felt like I was missing something. So if the functions were used elsewhere it would be required to unhook them then?

Also, is there a better way to accomplish this task, or is this pretty much it?

Comment: It's the good practice, and yeah if the function is hooked somewhere then you need to unhook and hook your own function.